# About CoreText memory growth

Tags: ios, memory, core-text

I use CoreText show text,but I find memory growth by Instrument Allocations.I present and dismiss ViewController,and Mark Heap !

I find a lot objects don't release.
like this:
Size:304  Responsible Library:CoreGraphics Responsible Caller:mem_alloc

Instrument show these objects are created by CTFrameDraw.

I'm sure all of Core Fondation objects are call CFRlease(),and leak of Instruments don't show memory leak.Now I doubt these objects are cached by system.like[UIImage imageNamed:].
Who can help me understand it, Thank You!